# How to prove that "exponentials beat polynomials" when dealing with limits?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

Consider the following theorem:

> Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then $n^p \alpha^n \rightarrow 0$.

To prove this, we will first note that
$$
r_n := \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)^p\alpha^{n+1}}{n^p\alpha^n} = \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^p \alpha \rightarrow \alpha < 1
$$
by the Algebra of Limits. Thus far, I understand this proof without problem. However, it now goes on to say that, from the above, we can tell that the ***sequence is strictly decreasing***. This is the part of the proof that I do not understand. How does the above tell us that the sequence is decreasing?

Comment: Consider two positive numbers, $a$ and $b$. Then $a < b $ iff $a / b < 1$.

Comment: basically you wrote $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$. It's easy to see that $a_n>0$ for each $n$, so multiply both sides by $a_n$ to get the result

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that the sequence is strictly decreasing.  What is true is that it is *eventually* strictly decreasing.  That is, there exist $N$ such that $a_N>a_{N+1}>a_{N+2}>\cdots.$

To prove this, we need to use the definition of what it means for $r_n$ to converge to $\alpha$.  This means that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $|r_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.  In particular, let's pick $\epsilon=1-\alpha$.  Then we get an $N$ such that $|r_n-\alpha|<1-\alpha$ for $n\geq N$, which implies $r_n<1$.  (A shorter intuitive version of this argument is: since $r_n$ is getting close to $\alpha$ and $\alpha<1$, $r_n$ must eventually always be less than $1$.)

So we have $r_n<1$ for all $n\geq N$.  Since $a_{n+1}=r_na_n$ (and $a_n>0$), this means $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all $n\geq N$.  That is, the sequence is strictly decreasing for $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's only true that the sequence is strictly decreasing *for sufficiently large $n$*; take for instance $p=100, \alpha=\frac12$.

To prove your statement with the 'for sufficiently large $n$' qualifier, consider the following: since your sequence of ratios $r_n$ converges to $\alpha\lt 1$, you can pick some $\beta$ with $\alpha\lt\beta\lt 1$ and show that there's some $N_0$ with $r_n\lt\beta$ for all $n\gt N_0$ (why?). Now $a_{n+1}=r_na_n\lt\beta a_n\lt a_n$ for those $n$.